# In chrome, when learing React, I find a output with a lighter color in the console, what is it mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, jsx

### this is what I writed

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, memo } from "react";

const Child = memo(() => {
  console.log("refresh");
  return <h1>Child</h1>;
});

export default function App5() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState("123");

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{num}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(345)}>刷新一下</button>
      <hr />
      <Child />
    </>
  );
}
```

### this is it's output

[image]

> you will see the second 'refresh' with a lighter color , but in the video I am learning, it only has the first output

1. what is it from?
2. how to fix it(only one 'refresh')?

Comment: The first one is the output of the console.log; the second one is a return value (I believe from the `memo` function.)  This is not a bug, and it's unrelated to React. Different browsers display this differently, which is probably why the video you're watching looks different; but it's normal for the console to show both output and return values